# spring-boot-devtools disables debugging, cannot hit breakpoints

Tags: java, maven, debugging, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

I am using devtools in spring-boot.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I run in debugging mode, but I cannot hit any breakpoint, the v is missing from the breakpoint indicating the class has not loaded. If I remove the devtools dependency from POM, the breakpoints start hitting. Is there a way I can use devtools and hit the breakpoints also ?

This is how I run it in debugging mode :
[image]

Using the debug mode here.

Comment: How are you running in debugging mode?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson The debug option on Intellij.

Comment: On your application's main class or the `run` goal of Spring Boot's Maven plugin?

Comment: maven plugin. See the above image.

Comment: If you're running it with Maven you're likely not running it with Devtools.

Comment: I don't know how, but I started hitting the breakpoints after I started it with debugging main class, then I started it in debug mode with maven goal, it worked. I am using devtools. It gives me the live-reload functionality when I run with maven.

Comment: The same is occurring to me, as soon as I add the dependency to `spring-boot-devtools`, breakpoints are not hit. I remove it, and breakpoints get back to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I found a workaround. Use additional flag:

```
-Dspring-boot.run.fork=false
```

Possible cause(20.2 Automatic Restart):
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.9.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html

As long as forking is enabled, you can also start your application by using the supported build plugins (Maven and Gradle), **since DevTools needs an isolated application classloader to operate properly**. By default, Gradle and Maven do that when they detect DevTools on the classpath.